# New Relic- What happens if I exceed the recommended limit of 2000 custom instrumentation metrics?

Tags: newrelic

In the [docs for custom instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/net-custom-instrumentation), New Relic recommend not to exceed 2000 metrics.

What would happen if I did exceed this number?

Does exceeding it by a small number (say 1 or 2 metrics) have the same effect as a large number (say hundreds or even thousands)?

If I had a testing environment with an issue I wanted to diagnose, could I choose to track say 5000 metrics temporarily and get still get data on all of those metrics? (I'd accept some temporary performance degradation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2000 metric number is based on trying to ensure that the application is producing useful metrics and to avoid metric grouping issues:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/other-features/metrics/metric-grouping-issues

The idea being that if you are generating more than 2000 custom metrics, the usefulness of those metrics is called into question.  Often in cases where more metrics are generated, those metrics contain unique segments which are not grouped together to give a clear picture of the *performance* of the application.

For instance, a metric with a unique segment may contain things like account ID's or URI's.

If you're interested in getting unique information about individual transactions, Insights is the way to go.

However, 2000 is not a hard limit.  At this point it will trigger a review of your metrics though.